# How can I run a WordPress site with Docker?

Tags: docker

Let me give you more details, I am new to Docker but not to WordPress.
My computer has Windows 8 OS.
I was given access to a repo at github, the repo contains all the files for WordPress inside a wordpress folder on the root.
At the root there is nginx.conf file and a docker-compose.yml
Inside the wordpress folthere the is a docker-entrypoint.sh file and a 
Dockerfile file.

The question is, 
How can I run the site locally so I can edit the site and push the changes to the repo when I am sure the site is working?

I get the following output when I exec docker-compose up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 68, in main
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 118, in perform_command
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 926, in up
  File "compose\project.py", line 388, in up
  File "compose\project.py", line 614, in warn_for_swarm_mode
  File "site-packages\docker\api\daemon.py", line 90, in info
  File "site-packages\docker\utils\decorators.py", line 47, in inner
  File "site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 183, in _get
  File "site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 488, in get
  File "site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in request
  File "site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 596, in send
  File "site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 423, in send
  File "site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 595, in
 urlopen
  File "site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 363, in
 _make_request
  File "httplib.py", line 1042, in request
  File "httplib.py", line 1082, in _send_request
  File "httplib.py", line 1038, in endheaders
  File "httplib.py", line 882, in _send_output
  File "httplib.py", line 844, in send
  File "site-packages\docker\transport\npipeconn.py", line 31, in connect
  File "site-packages\docker\transport\npipesocket.py", line 22, in wrapped
  File "site-packages\docker\transport\npipesocket.py", line 50, in connect
pywintypes.error: (2, 'WaitNamedPipe', 'The system cannot find the file specifie
d.')
Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

Thanks

Comment: You should really need the documentation. Docker is like an isolated machine, you can just install docker. I also recommend you to use `docker-compose` for your server. You'll find some examples here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/, there is one for wordpress also.

Comment: Install docker, install docker-compose, clone the repo, then keeping the working directory as the one which has `docker-compose.yml`, run `docker-compose up`. By what you said, I figure out that the things are already setup inside `docker-compose.yml` file

Comment: @Ayushya I did what you suggested and I added the output to the question because it is too long for a comment. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Is it a possible duplicate of [Docker Compose Up gives “The system cannot find the file specified.” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42052270/docker-compose-up-gives-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-error)

Comment: Take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/565) Discusses exactly same error as yours. Do a bit of googling with the error you get and hopefully you might find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information over here https://docs.docker.com/samples/wordpress/ there is already an official docker image for wordpress you can use.

All you need to do is running:

```
docker run --name some-wordpress --link some-mysql:mysql -d wordpress
```

This will automatically pull the wordpress image and will run a new container based on it.

Notice to use `-p 8080:80` to map the internal container port used by wordpress to the host port 80.

If your intention is not to use the existing wordpress image but to create a customized one based on their sources you can take a look at way their `Dockerfile` and customize it for your need.
The `Dockerfile` is basically a script used for creating a docker image.
For simple use cases taking their Dockerfile and put it on your machine, edit it and add `COPY` commands to copy files from your machine to the image.
Then build the image using the `docker build` command, and run it using the `docker run` command.

Comment: I think that was already done by the devops guy, I have to work on the project locally.
So I need to run locally, update the files in the repo and after I see the changes locally in the browser, I have to push the changes to the repo.